# Is there best practices example projects which is using Typescript & Angular & MVC5 C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, typescript

I am learning Angular and Typescript as I need to know them for the front end part of ASP.NET MVC project. Is there a opensource project where I can find all of that technologies implemented in a way that shows the best way to do it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/786205/ASP-NET-MVC-bundling-minification-with-angularjs-a
may help.

Comment: Given the support built into Visual Studio for it, TypeScript is well worth learning *standalone*. Then just apply Angular coding (learned from RAW JS Angular training).

Comment: I found something very useful - SideWaffle - this is an Visual Studio extension which have a nice templates for angular controllers, services... and also typescript Angular templates. MVC wll be just for the service calls, and also to add in the bundles the generated javascript in the pages.